# Excel - when I click on any cell from the group (set by me), I'd like to highlight all of the 'connected' cells instantly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, highlighting, cells

Example of what I want.

We have an excel spreadsheet.

I want to 'group' i.e. E3, E6, E10 (NOT E4, E5, E7 etc... that's the point) cells so if I click of any of them, all of them will be highlighted.

So let's say, I click on E3 so E3, E6, E10 are marked and I can do mass operations on them instantly.

I have excel 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this fixed range, put the following code into the `ThisWorkbook` code module in the `SheetSelectionChange` event.  It should then operate on any sheet in the workbook.  Should get you going to consider generalising it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E3, E6, E10")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("E3, E6, E10").Select
    End If
End Sub
```